# Laravel 5.8 Eloquent doesn't quote values on firstOrCreate

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

Laravel 5.8 newbie. Receiving data in json format from an api, converting in array, and trying to save it on the db.
the firstOrCreate is returning a sql error cause one filed has commas into it and Eloquent is not quoting the values.
So doing

```
$order = Connector::firstOrCreate($connector);
```

where the $connector array has field like:

```
'description' => 'bla bla, bla bla, bla. Bla bla bla, bla'
```

Is there a way to make Eloquent auto quoting values (i.e. in the .env file)?

`php artisan tinker` and then

```
DB::connection()->getPdo();
```

returns:

```
PDO {#2937
     inTransaction: false,
     attributes: {
       CASE: NATURAL,
       ERRMODE: EXCEPTION,
       AUTOCOMMIT: 1,
       PERSISTENT: false,
       DRIVER_NAME: "mysql",
       SERVER_INFO: "Uptime: 453  Threads: 8  Questions: 203  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 25  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 15  Queries per second avg: 0.448",
       ORACLE_NULLS: NATURAL,
       CLIENT_VERSION: "mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 7cc7cc96e675f6d72e5cf0f267f48e167c2abb23 $",
       SERVER_VERSION: "5.5.5-10.3.15-MariaDB-1:10.3.15+maria~bionic",
       STATEMENT_CLASS: [
         "PDOStatement",
       ],
       EMULATE_PREPARES: 0,
       CONNECTION_STATUS: "127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP",
       DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE: BOTH,
     },
   }
```

Comment: I think that should be enabled by default. Get into `php artisan tinker` and then write: `DB::connection()->getPdo();`. What do you get?

Comment: i edited my post to answer to you